# Apache2 Redirect Trailing Slash Not Working

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

I have attempted to read various documentation, as well as other answers online, and I cannot find a solution to my problem.

**Here is my issue:**

I have a permanent www to non-www redirect setup to point traffic from www.example.com to example.com

This works, but I am having issues when trying to visit specific urls. For example:

We have three PDFS that we would like people to be able to download via:

***example.com/paper/somepdfname.pdf***

When i visit the url like this it works, but if I try to visit something like this:

***www.example.com/paper/somepdfname.pdf***

The browser gets redirected, and strips one of the slashes out, resulting in "the site cannot be reached error". This is the url I end up with in the browser:

***example.compaper/somepdfname.pdf***

I think its pretty clear that I need to somehow make sure there is a forward slash put before the paper, but I do not know how to do this. Below you will find my .htaccess directive for handling the redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Rewrite logging can help you figure out where the slash is being removed. You can use [RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) in Apache 2.2, or [LogLevel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) in Apache 2.4.

Comment: you would save hassles like this defining virtualhosts as necessary and using redirect/redirectmatch in virtualhost context instead of catch-all rewriterule in per-dir context.

Answer (score 0):

Using `mod_rewrite` seems like an overkill for you. I recommend using [`mod_alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) and its [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive.

```
NameVirtualHost 111.22.33.44:80
<VirtualHost 111.22.33.44:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / http://example.com
</VirtualHost>
```